# File upload with Meteor + React failing silently

Tags: reactjs, meteor

Im using React and Meteor. I need to allow users to upload profile images.

Ive installed these packages:

```
cfs:standard-packages
cfs:filesystem
```

Ive defined my collection in images.js:

```
export const Images = new FS.Collection('images', {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem('images', { path: '~/uploads' })],
});
```

This file isn't imported into the server JavaScript.

It is imported into my React component (code below). My console.log does log the file and doesn't show me any errors. I also dont see any errors in Meteor's terminal.

```
import { Images } from '../../../api/images';

  const imgFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const file = e.target.profile.files[0];
    console.log(file);

    Images.insert(file, function(err, fileObj) {
      //If !err, we have inserted new doc with ID fileObj._id, and
      //kicked off the data upload using HTTP
    });
  };
```

However when I look at MongoDB there isnt any table called images so nothing has been saved. I also don't have any file or uploads folder added to my filesystem.

I have autopublish and insecure packages enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to defined a *managed collection* you need to do it in *both* your client and server code. `cfs` might be a bit unobvious because it doesn't take the form of a normal collection definition but it's doing it under the hood.

You need to import `images.js` into your server startup code.

Comment: Just for anyone else finding this thread I still found cfs:filesystem really hard to work with. Im going to use the Slingshot package when I actually launch (im just developing locally at the moment).

Comment: I replaced cfs with slingshot long ago, far better solution.

Answer (score 0):

cfs:standard-packages, cfs:filesystem are deprecated use [MeteorFiles](http://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files) instead. There is a section in there doc for react check it out.